# Azure table storage + Entity Framework 7 error on entity remove

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, entity-framework-core

I created context

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        options.UseAzureTableStorage("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .ForAzureTableStorage()
            .PartitionAndRowKey(b => b.Partition, b => b.Id);
    }
}
```

And Items class is

```
public class Item
{
    public string Partition
    {
        get { return "Items"; }
        private set { }
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to remove an Item using Entity Framework

Code to delete:

```
public void DeleteItem(Guid itemId)
{
    using (var db = new BaseContext())
    {
        var dbItem = db.Items.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == itemId);

        if (dbItem != null)
        {
            db.Items.Remove(dbItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I've got an error "Table or row not found on server". 
I can see in Storage Explorer that item is created and that it is removed on db.SaveChanges() but save changes always throw Exception.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Entity Framework 7 is in beta nightly builds right now, and any errors or bugs with it should probably be taken to the development team.  Table Storage Support could change on a daily basis since it is in active development.

Comment: Tracked by the issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1244

Comment: Please use azure storage library instead of EF: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/